# Dotted line with specific spacing using border-image

Tags: css

I want to/need to have a border of 1px thickness and dotted appearance, where the pattern is x-o-o-x-o-o etc. (dot, not, not, dot...)
This has to be done with border-image IIRC, but I went mad trying to create the image and applying it properly with the CSS statements.
Can anybody give me a hint how both has to be laid out?

Thanks and best!

Comment: Do you have your image available at a public URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it to work by making a 7x7 image with dots in the corners and in the middles of the sides. Like this.

[image]

And then they can be evenly spaced by making a 2px border, so that the corners and the sides of the element use one dot each (see the markers how the slicing is done). So the css would be something like

```css
border:2px solid transparent;
border-image: url(7x7.png) 2 2 round;
```